# Resolving Error in resource configuration

Tags: angularjs

I've been working through the below tutorial to get my head around AngularJS:
http://jphoward.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/end-to-end-web-app-in-under-an-hourpart-3/

Having adapted the the tutorial I get the below error and am struggling to find a solution. My understanding is that it is something to do with the Factory, originally I thought this was this could have been a malformed API request but I seem to be getting the right result in the browser.

Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array

The app.js code is:

```
//Main App
var app = angular.module("FixturesApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).
config(function ($routeProvider) {

    //Routing
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: 'list.html', controller: ListCtrl })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});


//Factory
app.factory('Fixture', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/fixtures/:id', { id: '@id'}, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});

//Directive
app.directive('sorted', [
function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="do_sort()" ng-transclude></a>' +
            '<span ng-show="do_show(true)">' +
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>' +
            '</span>' +
            '<span ng-show="do_show(false)">' +
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></i>' +
            '</span> ',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.sort_by = $attrs.sorted;

            $scope.do_sort = function() {
                $scope.sort($scope.sort_by);
            };

            $scope.do_show = function(is_desc) {
                return (is_desc != $scope.is_desc && $scope.sort_order == $scope.sort_by)
            }
        }
    };
}
]);

//Controller
var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location, Fixture) {
$scope.sort_order = "Id";
$scope.is_desc = false;

$scope.sortString = function (is_desc) {
    return is_desc ? "-" : "";
}

$scope.sort = function (col) {
    if ($scope.sort_order === col) {
        $scope.is_desc = !$scope.is_desc;
    } else {
        $scope.is_desc = false;
        $scope.sort_order = col;
    }
    $scope.search($scope.is_desc);
}

$scope.search = function (is_desc) {
    var fixtureList = Fixture.get({ order: $scope.sortString(is_desc) + $scope.sort_order }, function() {
        $scope.items = fixtureList.results;
    });
}

$scope.search(false);

}
```

Comment: What is the API you are trying to connect to ? What does it return ? Can you give a full path for  /api/fixtures/:id ?

Comment: The full URL is http://localhost:1062/api/fixtures. I've not published it yet and I'm using MVC's Web API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the string returned by your API is not valid JSON (JavaScript **OBJECT** Notation).
JSON consists of key:value pairs. For example :

```
{"myArray" : 
    [
    {"name" : "John"},
    {"name" : "Sarah"}
    ]
}
```

You cannot use directly an array => This is not valid JSON :

> ```
> [
>     {"name" : "John"},
>     {"name" : "Sarah"}
> ]
> ```

In short, your string should at least start with a `{` and not a `[`

See http://json.org/ for a complete explanation on the JSON format.

Comment: Thanks CCH, here is an example of my output if I browse to /api/fixtures:
[{"Id":1,"FixtureLeague":"League A","FixtureSeason":"2014","FixtureDate":"2014-05-05T00:00:00","Fixture":"Pyecombe v Haywards Heath","FixtureResult":null},{"Id":2,"FixtureLeague":"League A","FixtureSeason":"2014","FixtureDate":"2014-07-05T00:00:00","Fixture":"Worthing v Dale Hill","FixtureResult":null}]

Comment: I see the problem now, when a single record is returned (http://localhost:1062/api/fixtures/1) it misses off the square brackets []